# Is it possible to get list of parameters passed into a constructor?

Tags: python

Let's say I have this code snippet:

```
class A:
    def __init__(self, p1=1, p2=None, p3="test"):
        self.p1 = p1
        self.p2 = p2
        self.p3 = p3

a1 = A()
a2 = A(p1=2, p3="blah")
```

What I want to do is to somehow retrieve ONLY the named parameters that are passed into the constructor, not including the optional parameters with default values. To clarify, this does NOT mean to use inspect to return the list of all parameters. So for example for a1 this would be `{}` since the constructor is called with no parameters, and for a2 this would be `{"p1": 2, "p3": "blah"}` since the constructor is called with p1 and p3.
I've tried googling this and it seems that this isn't really possible, or at least I haven't found a way to do this.

inspect does not work because I want to do this for each individual instantiation. using locals() within the constructor also doesn't work because it includes the optional parameters as well even if they aren't explicitly passed in.

Comment: *one* approach would be to use `**kwargs` here

Comment: `**kwargs` will work, but it will also prevent errors from passing invalid named arguments.

Comment: Another approach, use a private object as a default value, e.g. `_UNSPECIFIED = object()`, then check your arguments: `if p1 is not _UNSPECIFIED: ...`

Comment: What do you want to do with them? Beware the [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/343832); give the context. For example, if you just want to log them, it'd be as simple as adding a decorator that takes `*args, **kwargs` and logs its `kwargs`.

Comment: It’s hard for me to think of good reasons to treat the same (default) arg value differently depending on whether it was passed explicitly by the caller or not.  Very strong “XY” smells, as wjandrea said.

Comment: What about positional arguments? You want to ignore them, right?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can intercept the arguments in `__new__` like this:

```
class A:
    def __init__(self, p1=1, p2=None, p3="test"):
        self.p1 = p1
        self.p2 = p2
        self.p3 = p3
        
    def __new__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        print(f"{kwargs = }")
        return super().__new__(cls)


>>> a1 = A()
kwargs = {}
>>> a2 = A(p1=2, p3="blah")
kwargs = {'p1': 2, 'p3': 'blah'}
```

Comment: this is a really good idea

Comment: This doesn't work as well if `A` subclasses anything other than `object`, though.

Comment: I'm going to try this out and see if this works. Since my class subclasses object I'm hoping this will work.

Answer (score 0):

Compare the values of the parameters passed to the constructor with their default values, this way if a parameter value is different from its default value, it mean it that it was explicitly passed during instantiation.

```
class A:
    def __init__(self, p1=1, p2=None, p3="test"):
        self.p1 = p1
        self.p2 = p2
        self.p3 = p3

        self.default_params = {'p1': 1, 'p2': None, 'p3': 'test'}
        self.passed_params = {k: v for k, v in {'p1': p1, 'p2': p2, 'p3': p3}.items() if v != self.default_params[k]}

a1 = A()
print(a1.passed_params)

a2 = A(p1=2, p3="blah")
print(a2.passed_params)
```

Comment: " it mean it that it was explicitly passed during instantiation." yes, but that doesn't deal with the case where `A(p1=1)` is used. In that case, you still get "none were explicitly passed", but `p1` was explicitly passed

Comment: If you want to use default parameter values to signal when an argument is explicitly passed, you'll need to use a sentinel that cannot be interpreted as a valid attribute value, and replace the sentinel with the "real" default in the body of the function.